# Replace an object in FabricJS?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

To implement a undo/redo functionality, I have constructed an array "`history`" that gets filled with the latest changes based on `canvas.on()` events.

console.log dump:

```
History: 
(3) […]
​
0: Object { target: {…} } //first object added
​
1: Object { e: mouseup, target: {…}, transform: {…}, … } //first object modified
​
2: Object { target: {…} } //another object added
​
length: 3
```

To walk back the stack of changes, I wanted to use `history[step].target` which contains the modified object at this stage (`step`).

I now look for a method to overwrite an object in the object array of fabric.

The function `canvas.item(0)` gives the object at position 0 on the current canvas but how can I overwrite that object with a different object (from the `history[].target` array)?

Note: Solutions I found for a undo/redo are seemingly based on serializing the whole canvas into JSON and saving this into an array of JSONs. I didn't want to do this since it seems a bit unsophisticated to always serialize/unserialize the whole canvas with x objects in it just to undo a small change and the history contains many usefull informations about what was changed and on which object ect.

Note2: Of course I probably could just `canvas.remove(canvas.item(0))` and then `canvas.add(history[x].target)`, however this unfortunately messes up my object stack when there's more than one objects, as `canvas.item(1)` becomes `canvas.item(0)` and the reverted change now becomes `canvas.item(1)` (or 2, 3... ect depending on how many items on the canvas). When I then have like a list of objects displayed depending on their position in the object stack, this get's rearranged and could confuse the user.

Comment: have you looked at http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#insertAt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a simple example.

Given 2 rect on on a canvas, a function will add one back in the middle of those 2, and another will replace the one at position 0.

[canvas#insertAt](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#insertAt) does work as suggested from @gabriele-petroli

```js
var c = new fabric.Canvas('c');

c.add(new fabric.Rect({ fill: 'blue', width: 100, height: 100 }));
c.add(new fabric.Rect({ fill: 'green', left: 150, width: 100, height: 100 }));

var redRect = new fabric.Rect({ fill: 'red', left: 75, width: 100, height: 100 });
var purpleRect = new fabric.Rect({ fill: 'purple', left: 0, 
width: 100, height: 100 });

setTimeout(function() {
  c.insertAt(purpleRect, 0, true);
  c.insertAt(redRect, 1);
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/3.5.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="500" height="500" ></canvas>
```

Comment: Accepted this. Just to add to the example to make it more close to my question, it would work with `c.item(number)` but one has to keep in mind, that `number` starts with zero like array indices and accessing a `number` out of bounds crashes the app.

Comment: Since I have grouping objects available, I had to write a recursive function to find the elements I wanted to replace, then call this on the object's parent.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know it is not possible to overwrite an object.

But this might help for your Note2:

In addition to Gabriele Petriolis comment, you can position the object in the stack after inserting:

```
Canvas.moveTo()
Canvas.bringToFront()
Canvas.bringForward()
Canvas.sendBackwards()
Canvas.sendToBack()
```

See: http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html